# Why doesn't terra::spin() work in R?

Tags: r, error, terra

I am using a map that is rotated sideways. Terra has a function to address this problem, called spin

```
library(terra)

maize_requirement_2016 <- rast("./data/raw/BW_irrig_2016.nc") |>
 subset("BW_irr_crop=2") |>
  terra::spin(angle = 90)
```

but when I try to use it, I get an error:

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘spin’ for signature ‘"SpatRaster"’
```

The dataset I use is at this link https://springernature.figshare.com/collections/Global_Gridded_Dataset_of_Crop-specific_Green_and_Blue_Water_Requirements/4893084 and is called BW_irrig_2016.

Comment: The only thing I could get to work which was the equivalent of what (I think) spin does is terra::t() and then raster::flip(direction = 'horizontal')

Comment: The documentation for `spin` clearly says the function is intended for SpatVect, not SpatRast: https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/terra/html/spin.html

Answer (score 2):

The help for `spin` says:

```
 Spin (rotate) the geometry of a SpatVector.
```

and what you have is a raster, not vector, which we can see when you read the error message:

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘spin’ for signature ‘"SpatRaster"’
```

`terra` has functions `flip` and `t` which can be used to rotate rasters by 90 degrees.

`plot(r) ; plot(t(flip(r)))`

[image]

`flip(t(r))` will rotate the other way round by 90 degrees.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `library(raster)` you can do:

```
library(raster)

r <- raster(nrow=18, ncol=36)
m <- matrix(1:ncell(r), nrow=18)
values(r) <- as.vector(t(m))
rx <- flip(r, direction='x')
values(r) <- as.vector(m)
ry <- flip(r, direction='y')
```

Which will result, from this:
[image: 1]
to this:
[image: 2]

Comment: That's not really useful when this can be simply done in `terra`.

Comment: @Spacedman I didn't say it couldn't be done in `terra`. Because someone commented doing it with `raster`, I thought it would be easier to stick with it. If my answer isn't helpful I don't mind deleting it.